# Media embed data showing up as string instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, youtube

Okay so I built a small app that has some media embed data (like a youtube video) coming in the form of a string that will look something like this:

`"&lt;iframe class="embedly-embed" src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2Fl5dvu4feCFk%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dl5dvu4feCFk%26feature%3Dyoutu.be&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2Fl5dvu4feCFk%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube" width="600" height="338" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;"`

I can't remember what this is called, which is why it was hard for me to Google an answer. Regardless, I used `innerHTML` to try and add this `iframe` to the page. It doesn't work by itself so I'm using this ugly line of code to replace all the `&lt;` kind of stuff:

`element.innerHTML = embedData.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">").replace("&gt;", ">");`

I know that this is ugly and probably terribly underperformant, so I'm looking for a better/"more correct" solution.

Here's an extremely simplified fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cvco8c23/

Comment: Can you paste in your code as well? Specifically the code that has the `embedData` variable defined.

Comment: Added a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cvco8c23/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
var a = document.getElementById('test');

a.innerHTML = '&lt;iframe class="embedly-embed" src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2Fl5dvu4feCFk%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dl5dvu4feCFk%26feature%3Dyoutu.be&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2Fl5dvu4feCFk%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube" width="600" height="338" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;';

var v = a.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

var b = document.getElementById('test2');

b.innerHTML = v
```

That does it all in the DOM, but to do it behind-the-scenes use:

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
```

This will unescape the text in the document (i.e. readying it for presentation to the user), then return it unescaped.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxvmbdh1/)